# Build breaks unless run as sudo

Tags: c, makefile, clang

When trying to build a project with 4 targets, 3 will build without problem and the third will throw an error unless make or gcc are run as root with sudo. It gives the error:

```
ld: can't write output file: server2 for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see 
invocation)
```

Comment: try to remove `server2` file (using `sudo`) and retry.

Comment: what @Jean-FrançoisFabre said: the error says where the problem is, you can't write the "server2" output file.

Comment: I would guess, access rights in your file system aren't really a C related problem...

Comment: Thanks, turns out that I forgot to check the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I forgot to check the file permissions on server2. Just needed to use chmod.